# How to create new column which display the order line on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns, newline, addition

I just want to get new column which represent the customer order line starting from the 1. I already listed a rows based on purchase date. I just want to count orders for all buyers.1-2-3-4 for example. If the new buyer id come it return back to 1 again and counting from 1.

My desired output is like that;

```
**buyerid** /  **orderid** / **purchase_date** / **new_column**
1-----------100------01-01-2020--------1
2-----------205------14-01-2020--------1
2-----------245------05-02-2020--------2
2-----------289------13-06-2020--------3
3-----------404------02-03-2019--------1
3-----------508------05-07-2020--------2
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`row_number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html):

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by buyer_id order by order_id)
from t;
```